# Add an icon after product price on Woocommerce archive pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, icons

I am trying to add a custom icon after the product price in Woocommerce for a specific product category on shop page. So I would like to add an icon of a "fast delivery truck" after the price on all products from "FAST SHIPPING" product category.

I would like it to display that like in **wish.com** web site, like in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is what I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2 );
function prepend_append_icon_to_price( $price, $instance ) {

    if(is_product_category( 'fast-shipping')){      
        $icon = ' <i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i> ';
        $price = $icon . $price . $icon;
    }
    return $price;
}
```

But It doesn't display anything after the price.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include your relevant code, since it will be impossible for anyone to replicate your situation without it. Also, please don't ask multiple questions at once. Thanks.

Comment: ok, will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong hook since Woocommerce 3 and there are some errors in your code. 
**To display an icon after the price on the right** for "fast-shipping" product category, two cases:

1) On all Woocommerce archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2 );
function prepend_append_icon_to_price( $price, $product ) {

    if( has_term( 'fast-shipping', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && ! is_product() ){
        $price .= '<span style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span> ';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) On a specific Woocommerce product category archive pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'append_icon_after_product_price', 10, 2 );
function append_icon_after_product_price( $price, $product ) {

    if( is_product_category( 'fast-shipping' ) ){
        $price .= '<span style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span> ';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: This worked!! Well at least for the simple products. Is there a way to also make it work for variable products? Thanks a million!!

Comment: @Matt I have re-tested the code and it works on variable products too on my test server…

Comment: Ok.. I will take a second look at my other codes and see if I have something that is keeping it from working on variable products. THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: How would the custom css be written to position the icon to the far right? As it is now, the icon is displayed immediately after the price.

Comment: @Matt I don't have that on my side… As I use `<span style="float:right">` in my code it display the icon on the end right and not after the price…

Comment: Fixed the issue, had to set css on .price to inline-block and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use css before or after belong to the price tag :

```
    fa-shipping-fast:before{
            content: url(.....);
            width : ....;
            height : ....;
            ....
    }
```