# How to add an icon on each product page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My website is - https://tringtring.lk, i have added an icon next to the product price on my woocommerce site got the code from - [Add an icon after product price on Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092679/add-an-icon-after-product-price-on-woocommerce-archive-pages), but now i wanted to add the same icon on each product page with word - "Same Day Delivery Applicable" how can i do that. this is the page product goes to - http://tringtring.lk/same-day-delivery/

I have attached the the screenshot where icon has to display and the error!.

1. Error.
2. Where the icon displaying.
3. Where i want the icon to be display.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PBfG.jpg)

Comment: you want to add the icon to the title of each product's page?

Comment: No, next to the product availability.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to add an icon and text to the availability text on all your products you can use the `woocommerce_get_availability_text` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'add_icon_and_message_to_availabilty_text', 10, 2 );
function add_icon_and_message_to_availabilty_text( $availability, $product ) {
    $availability = sprintf( '%s<div><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i> %s</div>', $availability, __('Same Day Delivery Applicable', 'shop_product_page' ) );
    return $availability;
}
```

This code snippet should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: @thaiyoob-hamza - If this answer works for you could you mark the answer as accepted and possibly vote it up? Thanks!

Comment: it didn't work :( it's showing below the price it's ok but next to the availability code is visible and i want it to enable this option only on 1 category.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with that. Could you try to explain more clear where you would like the icon and text to show up?

Comment: In the product page it is displaying below the product price, i'm okay with position where it is. Please have a look - https://tringtring.lk/product/sokany-deep-fryer/ i haven't removed the code FYR. now next to the stock availability the code you gave is visible. and also i want to add the icon text to selected category like this - https://tringtring.lk/same-day-delivery/ Please have a look.

Comment: Could you edit your question with some screenshots of where exactly you would like the icon + text to appear?

Comment: Hi i have attached the image please check.