# add an icon after product price on woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hello as the title says.

i'm after a solution for wordpresss woocommerce with products that needs to have a added icon with a van.

same as the following link

[Add an icon after product price on Woocommerce archive pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092679/add-an-icon-after-product-price-on-woocommerce-archive-pages#new-answer)

However i've managed to made categories with fa fast-shipping and gotten the icon.

I've added the code

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'prepend_append_icon_to_price', 10, 2 );
function prepend_append_icon_to_price( $price, $product ) {

```
if( has_term( 'fast-shipping', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && ! is_product() ){
    $price .= '<span style="float:right"><i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i></span> ';
}
return $price;
```

}

but it still doesn't want to pop up on my product which i dont understand.

[Display Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlRpn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this. Try going to the product code(where your product page with the product is shown) which will be located in themes mostly and then go below the pic and add your icon. I hope this helps :) Let me know if you find it difficult to figure it out and ill help you

Comment: Dear Ganpatth.
It took me a bit time to crack that one but it's not extractly what i want.
I want the display picture of the product to have a icon like the link with the Wish product.
Click on the Display Picture

Comment: Hey! That is also possible. So in the product code itself you can use <a href and redirect it to the wishlist. So basically all products will have an ID. With the link, there will be a tag which you have to mention like $id and then it will automatically go and save the product to wishlist

Comment: Hmm would it be in some way possible to show that in a visual way such as in pictures? Also i want the icon down on the products display list not on every product tho. and only products in the store.